# Unable to Start Ubuntu with "Ubuntu" strange message

Tags: 20.04, grub2

I am no longer able to start my Ubuntu PC because once I get the GRUB boot menu and choose Ubuntu, the desktop doesn't load and I am stuck with a `Ubuntu [y/n]:` prompt. When I press <kbd>Y</kbd> or anything, it just repeats the message, as shown in the following picture:

[image: picture of prompt]

Comment: Can you start it in recovery mode? Can you start it with an older kernel? And please specify which version of Ubuntu and some hardware specifications you are using ( edit your question with the information).

Comment: Second that; please [edit] your question to include the requested information, else your question is likely to be closed.